# How to include jar lib in my Ant build

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have the below build file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="ClientAdvisor" default="compress">

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">

    </javac>
</target>

<target name="compress" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="dist/clientadvisor.jar" basedir="build/classes">

        </jar>
</target>


<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build" />
    <delete dir="dist" />
</target>

</project>
```

I also have a list of jar files in my lib folder needed to compile my source files. Every time I run the ant command however, I get 'Class does not exist' compile errors. I have tried the following

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
        **<classpath>
    <pathelement path="lib/*.jar"/>
</classpath>**

    </javac>
</target>


 <target name="compress" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="dist/clientadvisor.jar" basedir="build/classes">
             **<zipgroupfileset dir="lib/" includes="**/*.jar" />**
        </jar>
</target>
```

None of this however seems to resolve the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to playe multiple JAR files in the classpath I would use a `<fileset>`instead of a `<pathelement>`:

sample [from Apache Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

```
<classpath>
      <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      ...
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use `classpath` or `classpathref` attribute with [javac task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) like:

```
 <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir=".. lib dir.." includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
 <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="classpath">
```

OR

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
     <classpath refid="classpath" />
     ...
```