# Java run project with an external jar file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am working in an old project which uses java 1.8 and spring 4.3, the project is an XML based configuration.

I am facing an issue. There is a folder, let's say it's called cars, in which are many brands: ford, mercedes, etc. In every folder there is a jar file, which contains a versions and always changes. However I am trying to take that jar file and run it with the project.

I go in intellij at the **edit run configurations**, add the class path to the .jar file , and I am running it. Everything works (but I am not sure if the jar loaded) in my application. I am calling a replace template with component from the jar file, and I am getting that could not find that component.

I added as a dependency, and I can use it as a class, but when it comes to use it as a component it just can't find it.

In my xml I have:

```
<modules>

</modules>

<boot>
    
</boot>
```

Which are left empty, as I don't know how to configure them.

So, my question is: how do I start the app with that jar file, and how to I set this file to use the module? (and what to do if the version of this module is always changing?)

Comment: this seems to be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?rq=1

Comment: @JAsgarov project does not use maven at all...

Comment: So what does it use? Spring 4 and Java 8 is not THAT old it for sure uses maven or gradle

Comment: @JAsgarov ANT :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708198/how-to-include-jar-lib-in-my-ant-build